# ここからさきにはゆかせぬ sentence breakdown

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

In Castlevania Rondo of Blood, [Death fight starts with him saying those words](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QolUJ0PqI8o&t=7). Now I'm trying to figure out exactly what that means and grammar rules used in this sentence. Here's where I'm at:

ここ|から|さきに|は|ゆかせぬ

here|from|proceed|I|...

Obviously the ... should be something along the lines of `won't let you` but I can't find the correct translation on jisho.org. Did I even break (and translate) the first part of the sentence correctly? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is は and not わ.

Comment: @l'électeur right, I keep forgetting about that... Thanks!

Comment: Probably it's ここから先に行く（ゆく）-> 行かせる  -> 行かせぬ

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12440/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Interesting. I didn't know いく can be pronounced as ゆく.

Comment: @FlorianBaierl Taking into account link from Chocolate it would seem you're correct. That would make さきに mean probably beyond/ahead (so my own translation was incorrect) and now everything makes sense. If you'd write this as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

行く is pronounced ゆく here.

> ここから先に行く（ゆく）-> 行かせる -> 行かせぬ
>
> I will not let you go any further.

Related:

- [When ない becomes ぬ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18727/when-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-becomes-%E3%81%AC)
- [When is 行く pronounced as いく, and when is it ゆく?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12440/when-is-%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F-pronounced-as-%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F-and-when-is-it-%E3%82%86%E3%81%8F)